# Flutter Error: Too many positional arguments: 2 allowed, but 3 found. lib/main.dart:13 Try removing the extra positional arguments

Tags: firebase, flutter

How to fix this error Too many positional arguments: 2 allowed, but 3 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(

Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
Thank you for your help............................................

````
const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel',
    "High Importance Notifications",
    "This channel is used for important notifications",
    importance: Importance.high,
    playSound: true);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("A Message Just Showed Up : ${message.messageId} ");
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  try {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
    await setupLocator();
    runApp(Phoenix(child: MyApp()));
  } catch (error) {
    print('Locator setup has failed! ' + error.toString());
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              channel.id,
              channel.name,
              channel.description,
              color: Colors.green,
              playSound: true,
              icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("A new message");
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text(notification.title!),
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [Text(notification.body!)],
                )),
              );
            });
      }
    });
  } ```
````

Answer (score 1):

The constructor looks like this:

```
const AndroidNotificationChannel({
  @required this.id,
  @required this.name,
  @required this.description,
  this.importance = AndroidNotificationChannelImportance.HIGH,
  this.vibratePattern = AndroidVibratePatterns.DEFAULT,
});
```

The parameters are named so you need to do something like this:

```
const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    id:'high_importance_channel',
    name: "High Importance Notifications",
    description: "This channel is used for important notifications",
    importance: Importance.high,
    playSound: true);
```

Comment: sorry there was a mistake on line one can u review your answer  again please.

Comment: Answer still stands, those are names parameters which means that just passing strings isn't enough. Check edited answer.